# How do I modify existing function call?

Tags: vb.net

I have a Function that I no longer want to use and I am calling it. So I would like to use a different function but modify the call. How do I do this?

**Old Function**

```
    Shared Function DetermineDocumentTypeCodeWord(ByRef aobjXMLCaseDoc As XmlDocument, ByVal aintDocketEntryTypeCode As Integer, ByVal aintDocketEntrySubTypeCode As Integer, ByVal astrCaseCategory As String) As String
'
End Function
```

**Calling old function**

```
    objDocument = New Msc.Integration.Mncis.Library.v4.Document(DetermineDocumentTypeCodeWord(objXMLCaseDoc, CInt(objXMLNode.SelectSingleNode("@docketEntryTypeCode").InnerText), CInt(objXMLNode.SelectSingleNode("@docketEntrySubTypeCode").InnerText), objXMLCaseDoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("Case/CaseCategory").InnerText), _
DetermineDocumentName(CInt(objXMLNode.SelectSingleNode("@docketEntryTypeCode").InnerText), CInt(objXMLNode.SelectSingleNode("@docketEntrySubTypeCode").InnerText)), strDocumentDescription,                     Msc.Integration.Mncis.Library.v4.Document.GetMimeType(objXMLNode.SelectSingleNode("@binaryObjectType").InnerText), _
System.Convert.FromBase64String(strDocumentObjectString), strDocumentSecurityCodeWord)
```

**New function**

```
    Private Shared Function CaseHasDomesticNoContactOFPChips(ByRef aobjXMLCaseDoc As XmlDocument) As Boolean
'
End Function
```

**How do I modify the following call of the old function to call the new 
Function?**

Modify this call

```
objDocument = New Msc.Integration.Mncis.Library.v4.Document(DetermineDocumentTypeCodeWord(objXMLCaseDoc, CInt(objXMLNode.SelectSingleNode("@docketEntryTypeCode").InnerText), CInt(objXMLNode.SelectSingleNode("@docketEntrySubTypeCode").InnerText), objXMLCaseDoc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("Case/CaseCategory").InnerText), _
DetermineDocumentName(CInt(objXMLNode.SelectSingleNode("@docketEntryTypeCode").InnerText), CInt(objXMLNode.SelectSingleNode("@docketEntrySubTypeCode").InnerText)), strDocumentDescription,                     Msc.Integration.Mncis.Library.v4.Document.GetMimeType(objXMLNode.SelectSingleNode("@binaryObjectType").InnerText), _
System.Convert.FromBase64String(strDocumentObjectString), strDocumentSecurityCodeWord)
```

Comment: Leave the old code as it is now, but inside old function call the new function. It seems that you have the required parameter (the XmlDocument) for the new function to pass along

Comment: The old function need to be deleted and use the new one CaseHasDomesticNoContactOFPChips

Comment: Then pass all your code and remove it

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. My code is now working.